# How to print out dictionary keys and values by the values lowest to highest and print them on a line

Tags: python

I'll try and reexplain my question down here. I'm trying to create a program which will allow the user to input a players name and their jersey number which will put it into a dictionary. The next function will read the dictionary and print out Player Name: NAME, Jersey Number: NUMBER where name is the name in the dictionary and number is their corresponding jersey number. I can't figure out how to make it so that the names and corresponding jersey number are organized by the number. Here is what I have so far:

```
def print_roster(team):
   team1=sorted(team.values())
   for x in range(len(team)):
      print('Player Name: %s, Jersey Number: %d' % (NAME, team1[x]))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-to-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def print_roster(team):
  for a, b in sorted(team.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1]):
     print(a, b)
```